# When I try to install any module with npm, it throws error EMAXREDIRECT

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to install modules via npm and I'm getting the error:

> npm ERR! code EMAXREDIRECT
>   npm ERR! maximum redirect reached at: https://registry.npmjs.org:443/

This is happening for every module I had tried to install. 
Also, I already had reinstalled node + npm, and it's not working yet.
I didn't found people with a similar issue... does anybody know what could be and how to solve it?

[error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vYkj.png)

Comment: The issue was solved...

I actually don't know exactly what happened but I could solve it with the following commands:

> npm config delete proxy
> npm config delete https-proxy
> npm config delete strict-ssl

It seems that I had some proxy configuration on my machine and I had to delete it all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Haysa 
Try setting registry and then running these commands.

> npm config rm proxy 
>    npm config rm https-proxy